# How to integrate office 365 with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, azure, office365

I am trying to integrate office 365 in asp.net application from many days; But haven't found any concrete information. After visiting the links, I came to know Azure subscription is mandatory.

However, If I want to access other users data(For e.g. Appointments, contacts etc), then what is the recommended approach ??. I have visited many links but not found any good solution.

Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

An Azure subscription used to be required if you wanted to access the Azure Management portal to manually create app registrations to obtain client IDs and secrets. That's no longer the case: http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/access-azure-active-directory-portal-from-your-office-365-subscription/.

But as the other answer says, you don't need an Azure subscription, just an Office 365 tenant.

Comment: Johnstron Whats the difference between Azure subscrption and office 365 tenant ?? I have mail ID associated with Office 365; But I cannot login onto azure with that. Also, application required TenantID, this will get only from azure, right ?

Comment: An Azure subscription allows you to add services like hosted websites or databases, etc. Office 365 Subscription includes an Azure Active Directory, but not an Azure subscription. However, because you have an Azure Active Directory, you can manage it per the link I sent above.

Answer (score 0):

An Azure subscription is not mandatory at all. Most Microsoft tutorials deploy the appropriate application to Azure, but that's not necessary. Nevertheless, you'll need an Office 365 tenant to get the appropriate user data.

To get appointments and other data of a user you should use the Office 365 API announced at TechEd Europe this year. With this API you can work against mail, calendar, contacts and files. [This tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/build-your-first-aspnet-mvc-app) shows how you can build an ASP.NET MVC application which integrates with Office 365. Also the Office Developer group published a [starter project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-APIs-Starter-Project-for-ASPNETMVC) at GitHub.

If you want to play around and get familiar with the Office 365 API you can use [the sandbox](https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/) provided by Microsoft.

Comment: If azure subscription is not mandatory; then how can we get the TenandID which is required for authentication ? OR TenantID is not required at all ??

Comment: Behind the scenes Azure AD is used, but you already should have access with your O365 subscription. [Quote from this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx): *When you sign up for Office 365 for business or Office 365 developer, don’t worry, you already get AAD.* When using VS, with the tools installed, you don't need to interact with Azure AD, because [it handles everything for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/adding-service-to-your-Visual-Studio-project).

Comment: Agreed. But when I have downloaded the sample apps from the dev.office.com; It suggest in the we.config, "Add you tenantID here". So my question how can I get this ?

Comment: David, tenant ID is a GUID that identifies your Office 365 organization. Typically it comes back during the authorization flow. What sample are you looking at that requires you to hardcode it? Or are you talking about client ID?

Comment: @JasonJohnston Not clientID.. it is auto generated. TenantID they are copying from Auzure Management portal. It is correct ???

Comment: Which sample? I can't think of any reason to hard-code a tenant ID in your app code unless you're intent is to only allow your tenant to use the app.

Comment: @JasonJohnston OK.. the sample downloaded from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/starter-projects-and-code-samples

Comment: I spoke with the person who created that sample, and they did use the tenant ID to enforce single-tenant use of the app. Basically, the tenant ID is used when constructing the OAuth endpoint. There are instructions on how to obtain the tenant ID in the sample's readme file. The readme does say that you need an Azure subscription, but that's old information. What you really need is access to the Azure Management Portal, which you can get without a subscription (see my answer).